# How to show a map which is a big image?

Tags: android, image, image-processing, imageview

I got a png image which is 5000x5000. This image is some sort of map. I wanted to display the image in an imageview and this gave me an outOfMemoryException(of course). So i tried to set a sampleSize, but this decreased the resolution which makes the map not very usefull.

So basically I want to show this image and be able to zoom and scroll without resolution loses. What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a fan of [Dave Morrissey's `SubsamplingScaleImageView`](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view), which seems to cover what you want. Quoting the project documentation, it is:

> A custom image view for Android, designed for photo galleries and displaying huge images (e.g. maps and building plans) without OutOfMemoryErrors. Includes pinch to zoom, panning, rotation and animation support, and allows easy extension so you can add your own overlays and touch event detection.

Comment: That look pretty much to what I want. I'll check it out